# No Data getting the database PHP/MSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I recently converted my old mysql code to mysqli, and I think I am missing something. For some reason now I am not receiving anything in the mysql database, and I am not getting prompted for any alert messages. Any one have any ideas what I am missing?

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
include_once 'dbconnect_i.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $s_firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_firstname']);
    $s_lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_lastname']);
    $s_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_email']);
    $s_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_password']);
    $s_street_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_street_add']);
    $s_city_town_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_city_town_add']);
    $s_state_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_state_add']);
    $s_zipcode_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_zipcode_add']);
    $s_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_phone']);
    $s_bday = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_bday']);
    $s_newsletter = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_newsletter']);

    $s_firstname = trim($s_firstname);
    $s_lastname = trim( $s_lastname);
    $s_email = trim($s_email);
    $s_password = trim($s_password);
    $s_street_add = trim($s_street_add);
    $s_city_town_add = trim($s_city_town_add);
    $s_state_add = trim($s_state_add);
    $s_zipcode_add = trim($s_zipcode_add);
    $s_phone = trim($s_phone);
    $s_bday = trim($s_bday);
    $s_newsletter = trim($s_newsletter);

    $s_password = hash("sha256", $s_password);    

    // email exist or not
    $query = "SELECT student_email FROM studentdata WHERE student_email='$s_email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if ($result != false) {
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); // if email not found then register
    if($count == 0){
        if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO studentdata(student_username,student_firstname,student_lastname,student_email,student_password,student_street_add,student_city_town_add,student_state_add,student_zipcode_add,student_phone,student_bday,student_newsletter) VALUES('$s_email','$s_firstname','$s_lastname','$s_email','$s_password','$s_street_add','$s_city_town_add','$s_state_add','$s_zipcode_add','$s_phone','$s_bday','$s_newsletter')"))
        {
            ?>
    <script>
        alert('successfully registered ');

    </script>
    <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
        <script>
            alert('error while registering you...');

        </script>
        <?php
        }       
    } 
    else{
            ?>
            <script>
                alert('Sorry Email ID already taken ...');

            </script>
            <?php
    }

}

}
?>
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimal-ui">
                    <title>HarringtonEd Inc.</title>
                    <link href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon">
                    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <center>
                        <div id="login-form">
                            <form method="post">
                                <table align="center" width="40%" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_firstname">First Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="student_firstname" placeholder="First Name" required />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_lastname">Last Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="student_lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_email">Email</label>
                                            <input type="email" name="student_email" placeholder="Email" required />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_password">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="student_password" placeholder="Password" required />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_street_add">Street Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="student_street_add" placeholder="Street Name" required />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_city_town_add">City/Town</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="student_city_town_add" placeholder="City/Town" required />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_state_add">State</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="student_state_add" placeholder="State" required />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_zipcode_add">Zip Code</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="student_zipcode_add" placeholder="Zip Code" required />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_phone">Phone Number</label>
                                            <input type="tel" name="student_phone" placeholder="888 888 8888" pattern="[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}" maxlength="12" required />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_bday">Birthday</label>
                                            <input type="date" name="student_bday" placeholder="Birthday" required />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="student_newsletter">Subscribe to Newsletter</label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="student_newsletter" value="Yes" checked/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table align="center" width="40%" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="submit" name="btn-signup">Register</button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </body>

                </html>
```

Comment: When you debug this, are the queries executing against the database at all?  What is the response from the database?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Btw, this is invalid syntax `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")` and your code looks very familiar. Edit: Ah yes right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069604/login-page-passing-session along with a few of your questions that look similar and no solution but answers given.

Comment: Plus, you're using way too much code here, where that could be cut down by what I'd guess to about 40-60%.

Comment: This is my first time using php on a project. I have asked a few questions before with similar topics looking for different answers. This site is under development for me to learn the proper ways. I have the HTML site done, just working on adding a user registration to keep track of users.

Comment: Voting to close as Typo. "simple syntax issue in the database connection" in OP comment under accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query fails you show this

```
    <script>
        alert('error while registering you...');
    </script>
```

Which is a **useless** piece of information while under development. Use proper error reporting to find out what the error is.

```
echo mysqli_connect_error(); 
echo mysqli_error($conn);
```

That doesn't solve the problem, it just tells you what the problem is rather than others having to guess.

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue it was a simple syntax issue in the database connection.